# QuerydslPredicateExecutor problem MongoDB-Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to use MongoDB and  QuerydslPredicateExecutor to have custom query. I tried with the code below, but I have problem

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'WS': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
>   through field 'repository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'lineeRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Did not find a query class
>   it.polito.pedibus.Model.QFermateM for domain class
>   it.polito.pedibus.Model.FermateM!

I have this model

```
@Data
@Entity
@Document("linee")
public class FermateM {
    @Id
    public ObjectId _id;
        private String idlinea;
        private List<String> fermate;

    }
```

With this Repository

```
@Repository
public interface lineeRepository extends  MongoRepository<FermateM, String> , QuerydslPredicateExecutor<FermateM> {
    FermateM findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
    @Query( value = "{}", fields = "{idlinea : 1}" )
    List<String> getIDlinea();
}
```

and this code

```
@Service
@RestController
public class WS {

    @Autowired
    private lineeRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "lines", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> getIDlinee() {
        return repository.getIDlinea();
    }
}
```

My pom file is this

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring boot Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to import the Q class to the repository, since @Query uses it.
2. You should use querydsl mongodb, add querydsl-mongodb dependency

The code:

Application.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

FermateM.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Data;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;


import java.util.List;

@Data
@Document("linee")
public class FermateM {
    @Id
    public ObjectId _id;
    private String idlinea;
    private List<String> fermate;

}
```

repository

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.demo.QFermateM;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface lineeRepository extends MongoRepository<FermateM, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<FermateM> {
    FermateM findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
    @Query( value = "{}", fields = "{idlinea : 1}" )
    List<String> getIDlinea();
}
```

controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@RestController
public class WS {

    @Autowired
    private lineeRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "lines", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> getIDlinee() {
        return repository.getIDlinea();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring boot Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            <logOnlyOnError>true</logOnlyOnError>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: after you run mvn compile do you see the QFermate file under target/generated-sources ?

Comment: no, the folder is empty! it contain oly a folder called "annotations"

Comment: did you remove querydsl-jpa dependency? did you check under: target/generated-sources/apt

Comment: no.. :(  when I build it doesn' t generate QFermateM but no error is displayed. When I run the program compare the error that I post at the beginning..

Comment: I just built your code locally and it did generate the Q files, I think you didn't change the POM file, and you have unneeded imports of JPA. I'll Post the code..

Comment: Thankyou. But I dont understand why, but also creating new project (I use IntelliJ) and copying your code, I have the error.. Is there a structure of the java classes (under src/main/java/com.example.demo) that I have to follow? I put all togheter in this folder.

Comment: My application. proprieties is this server.port=8090
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=pedibusDB

Comment: are you compiling with intellij ?

Comment: sorry found my mistake, you need to import the Q class to the repository with: import com.example.demo.QFermateM;

Comment: Thaks. Now it works. I generate the QFermateM with "spring-boot:run".. Then the import work, and the project work! Thank you very much!